# Wordpress - custom PHP function to save multiple nodes inside XML into multiple user meta fields

Tags: wordpress, import

We have a XML containing multiple nodes inside one parent. I will give you the example below:

```
<PARENT>
            <Data>
                <DATE_FIELD>11.07.2018</DATE_FIELD>
                <SUM_AVG/>
                <DOUBLE_AVG/>
                <THIRD_AVG/>
                <FOURTH_AVG>45000.00</FOURTH_AVG>
            </Data>
            <Data>
                <DATE_FIELD>10.08.2018</DATE_FIELD>
                <SUM_AVG>546.45</SUM_AVG>
                <DOUBLE_AVG>472.50</DOUBLE_AVG>
                <THIRD_AVG>180.00</THIRD_AVG>
                <FOURTH_AVG>44453.55</FOURTH_AVG>
            </Data>
            <Data>
                <DATE_FIELD>10.09.2018</DATE_FIELD>
                <SUM_AVG>536.59</SUM_AVG>
                <DOUBLE_AVG>482.36</DOUBLE_AVG>
                <THIRD_AVG>180.00</THIRD_AVG>
                <FOURTH_AVG>43916.96</FOURTH_AVG>
            </Data>
            <Data>
                <DATE_FIELD>12.06.2023</DATE_FIELD>
                <SUM_AVG>995.85</SUM_AVG>
                <DOUBLE_AVG>23.10</DOUBLE_AVG>
                <THIRD_AVG>180.00</THIRD_AVG>
                <FOURTH_AVG>1009.23</FOURTH_AVG>
            </Data>
            <Data>
                <DATE_FIELD>10.07.2023</DATE_FIELD>
                <SUM_AVG>1009.23</SUM_AVG>
                <DOUBLE_AVG>9.80</DOUBLE_AVG>
                <THIRD_AVG>180.00</THIRD_AVG>
                <FOURTH_AVG/>
            </Data>
</PARENT>
```

We would like to store these multiple values inside different custom fields inside the wp_usermeta table (Table containing custom fields for Users), using **WP ALL IMPORT** plugin. By default, you have to manually assign corresponding nodes inside the settings of the plugin.

For this, I have tried to hook a custom PHP function into the "**pmxi_saved_post**" action, loop through the "**Data**" nodes & add each one to an appropriately sepparate named custom field. So, for each node inside "Data", we have to store it into a separate custom field.

The problem is that it doesn't store anything inside the **wp_usermeta** table.

Here is the code:

```
add_action('pmxi_saved_post', 'post_saved', 10, 1);

function post_saved($id) {
    foreach( $data as $key => $value ) {
  update_post_meta( $post_id, $key, $value );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to get it working, with the following function:

```
function wpallimport_post_saved( $post_id, $xml_data, $is_update ) {
    if(!empty($xml_data->PARENT){
       $xml = $xml_data->PARENT;
       $counter = 1;
       foreach($xml->Data as $counts => $data){
        foreach($data as $key => $user_meta){
            update_user_meta( $post_id, strtolower($key) . "-data-" . $counter , current($user_meta));
        }
        $counter++;
    }
}
}
```